# Calculating Azure pricing

Tags: azure

The price calculator Azure does not show option for us we inform the number of hours that we use his service. Is the price calculator Windows Azure calculating 24 hours of use per day during the month?

How can I calculate the amount I pay if I access the Windows Azure services for two hours for day throughout the month?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Azure pricing, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** The calculator shows both prices per hour and per month. Yet, the monthly price is *estimated* on average of (fully consumed) 744 hours per month.

**2.** You're paying for the resources you *consume*, not for the resources you *accessed*. That means that even if nobody visited your website/webrole for the entire month, you would still have to pay the compute cost (the bandwidth cost will be $0 though).